# How to handle 'IllegalBlockSizeException' when creating EntityManager with EclipseLink version 2.6.4?

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa

I'm using EclipseLink and Java Persistence API to connect to local database, however when I'm creating `EntityManager` object, I'm getting following error:

```
[EL Severe]: ejb: 2017-06-04 19:29:55.066--ServerSession(1644987969)--Exception [EclipseLink-7107] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Error encountered during string decryption.
Internal Exception: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-7107] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Error encountered during string decryption.
Internal Exception: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher
```

Error stack trace point at line where I create `EntityManager`:

```
private EntityManagerFactory factory;
    private EntityManager em;

    public JpaDatabaseConnection() {

        factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("blogspace");
        em = factory.createEntityManager();
    }
```

I've added eclipselink and java persistence API through Maven Dependencies and JDBC driver to project classpath. This is my persistence.xml file (located in META-INF directory in folder with project packages):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">

    <persistence-unit name="blogspace" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>pl.furman.server.database.entities.User</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/blogspace" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="blogserver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="123456" /> 
            <!-- EclipseLink should create the database schema automatically -->
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

What is the cause of problem and how it can be solved? I know that JDBC driver itself probably is working correctly because when I intentionally put wrong password into `persistence.xml` file I'm getting error about failed authorization. Database is set up and working because I can create queries and insert data into database from shell and from eclipse toad extension.

Thank you in advance for help.

Edit: Problem lies in user name and/or password in persistence.xml. When I changed it to user and password of different length, connection works without problems. However still I have no idea why that was happening.

Comment: Do you have somewhere in your code user password encyption functionality?

Comment: No, I didn't used password encryption functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can confirm the odd behaviour with *EclipseLink* version **2.6.4**, as I reproduced your setup . Here's the full stack trace:

```
Internal Exception: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:303)
    at demo.service.UserService.<init>(UserService.java:14)
    at demo.Runner.main(Runner.java:8)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-7107] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Error encountered during string decryption.
Internal Exception: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.errorDecryptingPassword(ValidationException.java:894)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.security.JCEEncryptor.decryptPassword(JCEEncryptor.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.updateLogins(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2404)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.updateSession(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2716)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:710)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:934)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:845)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.DESCipher.engineDoFinal(DESCipher.java:314)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.security.JCEEncryptor.decryptPassword(JCEEncryptor.java:109)
    ... 9 more
```

It seems, this relates to [a bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=512344) in `org.eclipse.persistence.internal.security.JCEEncryptor`. While debugging, I found that there are certain password lengths which cause the observed behaviour, e.g. for `123456`.

### Solution

Now the good part of my answer: This bug was fixed with version *2.6.5-RC1*. Moreover, it also works as expected with the latest **2.6.5-RC2** release candidate (available since June 2017). In case you have a Maven project, change the version string of the *EclipseLink* dependency like so:

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
     <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
     <version>2.6.5-RC2</version>
 </dependency>
```

If this is a standalone project, find the latest [2.6.5-RC2 jar file on Maven Central](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/persistence/eclipselink/2.6.5-RC2/eclipselink-2.6.5-RC2.jar). Just remove the old *jar* file and put the new one in the application's class path.

Btw, when I changed the PW to `123456789` in the database as well as in `persistence.xml` it worked even with the bugged version 2.6.4. Odd, isn't it?

Hope it helps.